# how to replace a string(after reading file)and store the updated content in a new file?

Tags: matlab

I am new at MATLAB scripting, I was trying to read the contents of a file(data_files) into an array, `C`, compare the array for a specific string('hello'), if that string is found, replace it with another string('ciao') and update the file accordingly and store it in a new file(newfile.txt). I have the following code, please help me figure out my error:

```
C = textread(data_files, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
file_content = fileread(data_files);
expr ='\hello';
fileread_info = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match');
length_fileread_info=length(fileread_info);
        if length_fileread_info >=1                            
        C = C(cellfun(@isempty, strrep(filetext,'hello','Ciao') ));
        end
fid = fopen('newfile.txt', 'wt'); 
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', C{:});
fclose(fid);
end
```

I think I am not implementing the `cellfun` correctly. I get the following error

```
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.
```

Advice, please!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This code here `strrep(filetext,'hello','Ciao')` is returning a char, it should be a cell. Check the output of that code before using it.

Comment: Why are you using cellfun in the first place? On another note, is the file too large to read in and store at one time or are they relatively small (a few MB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can yse `regexprep`:

```
>> newC = regexprep( file_content, 'hello', 'Ciao' );
>> fid = fopen('newfile.txt', 'wt'); 
>> fprintf(fid, '%s', newC);
>> fclose(fid);
```